# File upload using JForm

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, jform

I'm trying to use Joomla's ([JForm File Type](http://docs.joomla.org/File_form_field_type)) form for photo upload. After submiting the form and the file, the field of file remains empty in database. What is missing here ?

My field looks similar to one in jdocs:

```
<field name="myfilevalue" type="file" label="Enter some text" description="Choose an image from your computer with maximum 100KB" size="10" accept="image/*" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, you need to process the field manually in your models `prepareTable` function.

You can access the file using this:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$files  = $jinput->files->get('jform');
$file   = $files['myfilevalue']
```

The $file array then holds the following keys:

- error
- name
- size
- tmp_name
- type

You also need to actually move the uploaded file to the final destination. This can be done using `JFile::upload()`.

Also make sure your form has the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` set, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: You do have to process the field manually. This can typically be done in the model in the `prepareTable` function.